# Can I put two (or more) criteria in one WHEN of CASE...END clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers, case

Just like this:

```
SET v_tax_rate =
    CASE state
        WHEN 'AL', 'AK' THEN 0.04
        WHEN 'CA' THEN 0.06
        WHEN 'WY' THEN 0.03
    END;
```

I put 'AL' and 'AK' in one WHEN. But it doesn't work. I can't creat it successfully, receiving an error prompt.

Is it possible to do so in MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried `WHEN 'AL' AND 'AK' THEN 0.04`? I don't have MySQL, but it works in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion, and it doesn't work. Replacing AND with OR resulted the same.

Comment: Oh yea, of course you'd want `OR` there. What if you do `CASE WHEN state='AL' OR state='AK' THEN 0.04`. That's how I actually did it in Postgres.

Comment: That can work. But I feel it a little verbose. I wonder if there exist any simpler syntaxes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current [12.4 Control Flow Functions :: CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) syntax, understanding and correct handling of warnings, one option is to do something like:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_sta`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_sta` (
    ->   `state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL 
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_sta`
    ->   (`state`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('AL'), ('AK'),
    ->   ('CA'), ('WY');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `state`,
    ->   CASE `state`
    ->     WHEN `state` NOT IN ('AL', 'AK') THEN 0.04
    ->     WHEN 'CA' THEN 0.06
    ->     WHEN 'WY' THEN 0.03
    ->   END `result`
    -> FROM `tbl_sta`;
+-------+--------+
| state | result |
+-------+--------+
| AL    |   0.04 |
| AK    |   0.04 |
| CA    |   0.06 |
| WY    |   0.03 |
+-------+--------+
4 rows in set, 4 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AL' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AK' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'CA' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'WY' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'AL' = 0 /* FALSE */, 'AL' = 1 /* TRUE */;
+----------+----------+
| 'AL' = 0 | 'AL' = 1 |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        0 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AL' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AL' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another option (more verbose, but without warnings):

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   `state`,
    ->   CASE `state`
    ->     WHEN IF(`state` IN ('AL', 'AK'), `state`, NULL) THEN 0.04
    ->     WHEN 'CA' THEN 0.06
    ->     WHEN 'WY' THEN 0.03
    ->   END `result`
    -> FROM `tbl_sta`;
+-------+--------+
| state | result |
+-------+--------+
| AL    |   0.04 |
| AK    |   0.04 |
| CA    |   0.06 |
| WY    |   0.03 |
+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And another option:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   `state`,
    ->   CASE `state`
    ->     WHEN CASE WHEN `state` IN ('AL', 'AK')
    ->          THEN `state` END THEN 0.04
    ->     WHEN 'CA' THEN 0.06
    ->     WHEN 'WY' THEN 0.03
    ->   END `result`
    -> FROM `tbl_sta`;
+-------+--------+
| state | result |
+-------+--------+
| AL    |   0.04 |
| AK    |   0.04 |
| CA    |   0.06 |
| WY    |   0.03 |
+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bEBmkzPZ8ACpDdVnWQVJZc/2).

Comment: That can work. Thank you for your so careful and elaborate reply! It's so kind of you. Thank you!